# Insert image taken from a web url into SQL Server 

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I remotely took an image from web into my `<asp:Image>`, now I want to insert that image into SQL Server. Please help! I have a simple table `id (pk)`, my `image (image)`

Or is it possible to insert image taken from web  into SQL Server image datatype when only thing available to you is image url ?

thanks

Comment: the above solution if I can do will be great , but any other suggestion by which I can store user image along side its row in db and keep its image privacy is also wellcome

Comment: First of all - do NOT use the `Image` datatype anymore - it's been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Use `varbinary(max)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download Image from a URL using C#**

For using WebClient you might need to include the System.Net namespace.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
wc.DownloadFile(URL_Of_The_Image, FileName_You_Want_to_Store_It_As);
```

**Upload an Image into SQL Server table using OPENROWSET**

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeProfile
(
    EmpId INT,
    EmpName VARCHAR(50) not null,
    EmpPhoto VARBINARY(MAX) not null
)
GO  

INSERT EmployeeProfile (EmpId, EmpName, EmpPhoto)
SELECT 1001, 'Vadivel', BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\Images\Demo.jpg', Single_Blob) AS EmployeePicture
GO
```

Refer - http://vadivel.blogspot.in/2005/10/saving-images-as-blob-into-sql-server.html

Comment: its very helpful , one thing more

Comment: its very helpful , one thing more I want to save by giving relative path to my images folder ,it worked with absolute path of my PC

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is a URL you will have to use something like `WebClient.DownloadData(url)` to get it locally, keeping in mind a: it might not actually give you the image (referrer/auth checks etc), and b: copyright may apply.

Then it is simply a case of handing the `byte[]` to SQL server. You can pass a `byte[]` to a `SqlParameter.Value`, and for storage in SQL Server you can use the `varbinary(max)` type. I would also suggest storing the content-type that you get back from `WebClient.ResponseHeaders`, so you know what type of image it is.

Don't use the `image` data-type; that is obsoleted by `varbinary(max)`:

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

(source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old cow, but I figured there might still be someone looking for a solution (I was! ;-). I wrote a little SP just for downloading a single image (of pretty much any size) and importing it as a BLOB in a table called Pictures. Six lines of Python do the actual download and expect the URL and the desired name on disk as parameters. The Python code is executed by the SP. The Python code:

```
import requests
import sys
url = sys.argv[1]
fname = sys.argv[2]
myfile = requests.get(url)
open(fname, 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

Save it somewhere convenient as ImgDownloader.py.
Then we'll need a SQL table to store whatever we download in:

```
CREATE TABLE Pictures (
    PicName     NVARCHAR(40),    -- Any name you want
    PicFileName NVARCHAR(100),   -- The file name
    PicData     VARBINARY(MAX) ) -- The binary image data
```

And lastly the SP itself:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DownloadAndImportImage] 
    @URL VARCHAR(2000)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100), @FullFileName VARCHAR(500), @Query VARCHAR(2000), @RevURL VARCHAR(2000), @LZ VARCHAR(200), @PicName VARCHAR(40)

-- NINO
SET @URL = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@URL)), '')
IF @URL = '' OR LEFT(@URL, 4) <> 'http' RETURN

-- Basic settings
SET @LZ = 'C:\Temp\LZ'  -- Our temp Landing Zone folder for the downloaded images. No slash at the end

-- Clean up the LZ first. An aborted previous run may have left something there
SET @Query  = 'RD ' + @LZ + ' /s/q'
EXECUTE Master..xp_cmdshell @Query
SET @Query  = 'MD ' + @LZ
EXECUTE Master..xp_cmdshell @Query

-- Then figure out the file name and have Python download the file using some dynamic SQL
SET @RevURL       = REVERSE(@URL)
SET @FullFileName = @LZ + REPLACE(REVERSE(LEFT(@RevURL, CHARINDEX('/', @RevURL))), '/', '\')
SET @FileName     = REPLACE(@FullFileName, @LZ + '\', '')
SET @Query        = 'python.exe <path to your Pyton code here>\ImgDownloader.py ' + @URL + SPACE(1) + @FullFileName
EXECUTE Master..xp_cmdshell @Query

-- Insert the image on disk into the Pictures table
SET @PicName = 'Some description'
SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO Pictures (PicName, PicFileName, PicData) SELECT ' + '''' + @PicName + '''' + ', ' + '''' + @FileName + '''' + ', * '
SET @Query += 'FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk ' + '''' + @FullFileName + '''' + ', Single_Blob) AS IMG'
EXEC(@Query)

-- Lastly, clear the LZ again
SET @Query  = 'RD ' + @LZ + ' /s/q'
EXECUTE Master..xp_cmdshell @Query
```

By executing the SP:

```
EXEC DownloadAndImportImage 'https://www.pocketfms.com/Graphics/SitesShared/FirstSolo.jpg'
```

you'll see the table Pictures receive a new row, with the image as binary data. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

This article has everything you need (and a lot more):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126421/Image-Handling-In-ASP-NET