# Inserting an image retrieved from a web url into a SQL Server database as a varbinary column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varbinary

I have a image url link that I need to store in a SQL Server database. I need to write something in SQL Server or SSIS to get that image from the URL.

The issue with the code shown here is the responsetext is `nvarchar(max)` and it should be `VarBinary(MAX)`.

This is just an idea to call a http request from the database. I think the solution will be to do it in a script component in SSIS, am I correct or does someone have a better idea?

```
DECLARE @status int
DECLARE @responseText AS TABLE (responseText nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @res AS Int;
DECLARE @url AS nvarchar(1000) = 'https://agriapp.azurewebsites.net/barcode/qr?id=LL-12345'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @res OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'open', NULL, 'GET',@url,'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'status', @status OUT

INSERT INTO @ResponseText (ResponseText) 
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'responseText'

EXEC sp_OADestroy @res

SELECT 
    @status, 
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),responseText) responseText 
FROM @responseText
```

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140065/insert-image-taken-from-a-web-url-into-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are getting in responseText is a base64 encoded, and you need to decode it, or convert it from base64 to varbinary. Check out this blog post:

### T-SQL: Easy Base64 Encoding and Decoding

https://medium.com/falafel-software/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding-872ad184bd7e

Answer (score 0):

If the image is under **8K** in size, you should be able to use your code but change:

DECLARE @responseText AS TABLE (responseText nvarchar(max))
to
DECLARE @responseText AS TABLE (responseText varbinary(max))

and change:
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'responseText'
to
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'responseBody'